# URLEncoder.encode doesn't work with cyrillic

Tags: java, android

I have an error when username in my app on android is in cyrillic.
I use TomCat server and Eclipse.

For name "Алексей", serverside threw to me this:

```
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path
> [/AppServer] threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 37:
> /AppServer/chat?name=???»?µ?????µ??
```

My code:

```
try {
        client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET
                + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")), new WebSocketClient.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect() {

            }

            /**
             * On receiving the message from web socket server
             * */
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got string message! %s", message));

                parseMessage(message);

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(byte[] data) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s",
                        bytesToHex(data)));

                // Message will be in JSON format
                parseMessage(bytesToHex(data));
            }

            /**
             * Called when the connection is terminated
             * */
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect(int code, String reason) {

                String message = String.format(Locale.US,
                        "Disconnected! Code: %d Reason: %s", code, reason);

                showToast(message);

                // clear the session id from shared preferences
                utils.storeSessionId(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error! : " + error);

                showToast("Error! : " + error);
            }

        }, null);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    client.connect();
}
```

As `URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")` doesn't help me, same "???»?µ?????µ??" =\

Any suggestions how to solve it?(

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to work here,

```
String name = "Алексей";
try {
    String str = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9
Алексей
```

Make sure the remote end is decoding `UTF-8`

Comment: Yep, it's work and output is what i need, but server is still threw me "???»?µ?????µ??"
Maybe problem with TomCat, but where? =\

Answer (score 0):

Encode it in previous script and put already encoded string solve this. Tomcat problem.